# Is there any way to move to specific slide without triggerring change event?

Tags: swiper.js

I am currently using swiper wrapper for angular https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-swiper-wrapper,
so basically I want to differentiate between manual slide that user performed and my own app pre-selecting active slide.

Whenever i use setIndex method (presumably equivalent to goToSlide at swiper js),it trigger all kind of changeEvent which manual slide change would also trigger(transitionEnd, slideChange, etc).

Is there any way to change active slide without trigerring those event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to do that by using function

setIndex(index, speed?, silent?)  // Runs transition to slide with given index.

by setting silent to true (slideChangeTransitionENd) event wont be called.
There should be better documentation about this.